# Free tools/softwares for office desk allocation

Tags: open-source, scheduling, office, resource-management, human-resources

Currently, my company does hot desking by using data in spreadsheets. It's difficult to manage it that way. Most of the workforce are customer service people. They work in different teams(region based) and shifts. The tool will be mostly used by a capacity management team for adding/updating the required information and communicating the allocations. There are solutions in the market but mostly are paid ones. Are there any free software/tools for such scenario?

Some tentative requirements:

1. should accept inputs such as number of employees, teams, team structure, team/employee shifts, number of desks(with state like available, unavailable), etc.
2. based on above inputs, it should generate a desk allocation report on demand.
3. should have provision to do manual changes in allocation.
4. good to have but not required - feature to send auto SMS/Email to employees with allocation info, interface for employees/team leaders so that they can view/populate the information themselves.

OS platform : Windows, Linux

PS - The above requirements aren't rigid. I would be happy to know about any tools which can ease manual effort of the described scenario.

Comment: You could visit https://alternativeto.net/ and give the name of some of the paid solutions & look for a free alternative. If you find something there, please post an answer here (and accept it), in order to help others in future